# How can we order a union query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, select, sql-order-by

I have a stored procedure like below in MYSQL:

```
    (SELECT 1 AS sort_col, col_a, col_b FROM t1 WHERE col_b LIKE %some% AND col_b LIKE %thing%)
    UNION
    (SELECT 2, col_a, col_b FROM t1 WHERE col_b LIKE %some% OR col_b LIKE %thing%)
 ORDER BY sort_col, col_a;
```

I want the result of first select show at first, but some results of the first are common in second too, and second select changed their sort_col to 2.(I can't use `LIMIT` in my selects)
what can I do for solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Use a sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   (SELECT 1 AS sort_col, col1a, col1b FROM t1)
   UNION
   (SELECT 2, col2a, col2b FROM t2)
) tbl 
ORDER BY sort_col, col1a;
```

---

Edit (after [OP's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17830444/revisions))

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  (SELECT 1 AS sort_col, col_a, col_b 
     FROM t1 
    WHERE col_b LIKE %some% 
      AND col_b LIKE %thing%)
  UNION
  (SELECT 2, col_a, col_b 
     FROM t1 
    WHERE col_b LIKE %some% 
       OR col_b LIKE %thing%)
) tbl
ORDER BY sort_col, col_a;
```

Comment: tnx but it doesn't work!

Comment: @Highlan - This is how it should work. Please show your sample data and expected result.

Comment: Please look at my edited question again.

Comment: Because some results in first select in common in the second too, the sort_col doesn't properly work!

Comment: @Highlan - I think you are missing something there is no logic to use SELECT * FROM (first select statement) UNION SELECT * FROM (Second SELECT). Both will result same. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f502/7

Comment: maybe, actually i have an ORDER BY at the end of each select. sorry, i forgot that

Comment: @Highlan - Is your problem solved or not?